# initialize html tag from angular type-script

Tags: html, angular, typescript

as shown in the below angular type script code, i would like to refer to the divisions mentioned in the below posted `.html` code using `document.getElementById`
the result of the log statement is `null`

please let me know how correctly to referece an html-tag in type-script

**.ts**:

```
  export class GridCellPopupOverlayComponent implements OnInit {
  isVisible = true
  container: any
  content
  closer: any
  overlay: any
  AoC: any
  AvgH: any
  Dist: any
  I: any

  constructor() { 
  }

  initHTMLElements() {
    console.log("html init")
    this.container = document.getElementById('idGridCellInfoPopupDiv');
    this.AoC = document.getElementById('idGridCellInfoAoCValueDiv');
    this.AvgH = document.getElementById('idGridCellInfoAvgHValueDiv');
    this.Dist = document.getElementById('idGridCellInfoDistValueDiv');
    this.I = document.getElementById('idGridCellInfoIValueDiv');
    this.closer = document.getElementById('gridCellInfoPopup-closer');
    console.log("this.AoC:",this.AoC)

  }
  }
```

**html**:

```
<div *ngIf="isVisible" id="idGridCellInfoPopupDiv" class="ol-popup">
<a href="#" id="gridCellInfoPopup-closer" class="ol-popup-closer"></a>
<!-- <span id="idGridCellLabel" class="label label-success">dsfdsfsa</span> -->
<div class="alert alert-success alert-sm" role="alert">
  <div class="alert-items">
      <div class="alert-item static">
          <div class="alert-icon-wrapper">
              <clr-icon class="alert-icon" shape="check-circle"></clr-icon>
          </div>
          <div id="idGridCellAlertText"class="alert-text">
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  <!-- <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close">
      <clr-icon aria-hidden="true" shape="close"></clr-icon>
  </button> -->
</div>


<div id="idGridCellInfoAoCValueDiv"></div>
<div id="idGridCellInfoAvgHValueDiv"></div>
<div id="idGridCellInfoDistValueDiv"></div>
<div id="idGridCellInfoIValueDiv"></div>
```

Comment: try using var instead of this.container, this.AoC etc, see if it works then

Comment: @MasterAzazel can you please provide some code

Answer (score 1):

You can get the elements from the `.html` by using `@ViewChild`/`@ViewChildren` decorators. Behind the scenes they are using `document.getElementById`. This is the correct way in Angular.

Also watch out for `ngAfterViewInit` lifeycle method in which you can access your references. View queries are set before the `ngAfterViewInit` callback is called. (form Angular documentation)

Here is the reference: https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild

Btw, you can omit `static: false` since it's default.

## TS file

```
import { HelloComponent } from './hello.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  name = 'Angular';

  @ViewChild('pRef', {static: false}) pRef: ElementRef;

    ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log(this.pRef.nativeElement.innerHTML); 
    this.pRef.nativeElement.innerHTML = "DOM updated succesfully!!!"; 
  }
}
```

## Template file

````
<hello name="{{ name }}" ></hello>

<p #pRef>
  Start editing to see some magic happen :)
</p>```
````

Comment: can you please provide some code

Comment: I added one simple example